# How to show/hide a section of content when a corresponding menu item is clicked, while hiding all other content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the contents of a section when a menu item is clicked, while hiding the contents of all the other sections on the page.

This is the html:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="navServe">services</li>
  <li class="navContact">contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<section class="services s-h">
 <h1>Contents of services section</h1>
</section>

<section class="contact s-h">
 <h1>Contents of contact section</h1>
</section>
```

The css is as simple as using a display none to hide the sections that contain the content.

And I've been trying this jQuery:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
$(".content").children(".s-h").css("display", "block");
$(this).siblings(".s-h").css("display", "none");
});
```

But the jQuery is not finding the active section. In fact it's displaying the content of both sections (services and content) when either of the menu items are clicked. How can I make the jQuery find the content of the corresponding menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your HTML, you can do it like this:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
    $("section.s-h").css("display", "none");
    if ($(this).hasClass("navServe"))  $("section.services.s-h").css("display", "block");
    if ($(this).hasClass("navContact")) $("section.contact.s-h").css("display", "block");
});
```

As you add more sections, this will soon get longer though. In order to improve it, you'll have to change your HTML a bit (much like @Ravi's suggestion):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="navServe" data-target="section.services.s-h">services</li>
        <li class="navContact" data-target="section.contact.s-h">contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="services s-h">
    <h1>Contents of services section</h1>
</section>

<section class="contact s-h">
    <h1>Contents of contact section</h1>
</section>
```

The `data-target` attribute can contain any CSS selector that points to your `section` tags.

Then your script can be:

```
<script>
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
    $("section.s-h").css("display", "none");
    $($(this).data("target")).css("display", "block");
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest version so far and works just how I wanted. The only issue I have with this is that it would get a bit long if you had lots of content. Thankfully, I'm only going to have a few sections, so I'm going to use this. A DRY-er version would be absolutely ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

On click check which nav is clicked, by jQuery `hasClass` function and then show and hide div accordingly. Like this:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass("navServe")){
  $(".services").css("display", "block");
  $(".contact").css("display", "none");
 }else{
  $(".contact").css("display", "block");
  $(".services").css("display", "none");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Give your `<li>` tags an `id` ,

```
<li class="navServe" id="tab1">services</li>
<li class="navContact" id="tab2">contact</li>
```

**2**.Give id's to your sections ,where contents are shown

```
   <section class="services s-h" id="section1">
     <h1>Contents of services section</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="contact s-h" id="section2">
     <h1>Contents of contact section</h1>
    </section>
```

**3**.Place this on your `script`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#tab1").click(function(e) {
            $('#section1').css({"display":"block"});
            $('#section2').css({"display":"none"});

        });

$(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#tab2").click(function(e) {
            $('#section1').css({"display":"none"});
            $('#section2').css({"display":"block"});

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first establish a relationship between the nav and the sections. Add a data-target in the nav nodes to point to the appropriate sections.

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="navServe" data-target=".services">services</li>
  <li class="navContact" data-target=".contact">contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<section class="services s-h">
 <h1>Contents of services section</h1>
</section>

<section class="contact s-h">
 <h1>Contents of contact section</h1>
</section>
```

You can then do this:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
   $(".s-h").hide();
   var elem = $(this).attr("data-target");
   $(elem).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/eu2q8fwo/)